# Forcing a Cocoa text field to end editing

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I have a view based gui that contains a text field for each gui item.  When I select another menu item I want my text fields to exit out of editing mode.  I could not find anyway to do this in the nsTextField docs.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to tell the window to remove first responder status from the control:

```
[[textField window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

This will end editing and remove focus from the text field.

Comment: Works fine in Yosemite here. Are you calling from the main thread?  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[textField.window makeFirstResponder:nil];});`

Comment: I'm hitting a similar issue when I have a focused `NSTextField` and click on an `NSSlider` ... I can add a `mouseDown` handler to `NSSlider` to grab focus, but I'm wondering if there is a good way to bake this into `NSTextField` itself, so it looses edit mode upon clicking any `NSControl` ...

Comment: Would this work if called directly on window inside window controller's `windowDidLoad` method in swift? I assume it would have the same effect, but not working for me. Or am I confusing this with something else?

Comment: `windowDidLoad` does not necessarily mean that the window is key. You could use the `NSWindowDelegate` method `windowDidBecomeKey(_ notification: NSNotification)` and when the window becomes the key window, make the first responder `nil`. You would have to manage this so that you can actually make the window accept first responder status :-)

Comment: `[self.view.window makeFirstResponder:nil]` may also work in most cases, and is more generic.

Answer (score 12):

The following solution from [cocoabuilder.com - Stop edit session with a NSTextField](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/230825-stop-edit-session-with-nstextfield.html#230830) works for me both on OS X 10.9 and OS X 10.10 for Objective-C and on 10.10 for Swift.

Here is Objective-C version:

```
@implementation CustomTextField

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    self.target = self;
    self.action = @selector(action:);

    return self;
}

- (void)action:(NSTextField *)textField {
    // Make something else first responder, something neutral 
    // (or can be a fake invisible element)
    [self.window makeFirstResponder:self.window.contentView];

    // Other code
}

@end
```

Background: accepted solution in this topic never worked for me on OS X 10.9 and 10.10 so instead of calling `[[textField window] makeFirstResponder:nil];` as it suggests - I needed to call `makeFirstResponder` with some non-nil NSResponder subclass (this can be either NSWindow's content view or NSViewController's view that both work in my case or some fake NSTextField view which is not visible to user for more complex cases).

Important detail: `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder]` must be invoked exactly within NSTextField's action selector like my example demonstrates. No other place in NSTextField method pipeline did work for me (textDidEndEditing:, textShouldEndEditing: or control:textShouldEndEditing:)

Comment: even though strange, this also was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: indeed this works while the accepted answer doesn't, in Yosemite

Comment: If you had called the method from the answer above in viewWillLayout, you would have done everything in one row without creating any subclasses.

Comment: This solution works for me, but only when Enter is pressed, it still doesn't work when TAB button is pressed.

Answer (score 9):

i know this is an old question, but in case anyone is wondering about swift 3, it only worked for me with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.window?.makeFirstResponder()
}
```

Swift 4.2 udpate,  `nil` makes the window its first responder.  Otherwise throws error.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
}
```

Comment: I don't know about saving my life but this really helped. :) I also want to point out that in my case it was not makeFirstResponder but resignFirstResponder that had to be wrapped in the Dispatch Queue.

Answer (score 0):

This command should be used in viewWillLayout and if need in viewWillAppear and . And that's all. No subclasses and parallel threads.

```
[textField.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

This works well with the main window. But this does not work well with modal windows.

For modal windows use viewDidAppear or dispatch_async:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [textField.window makeFirstResponder:nil];
    });
```